# How to create a custom ProgressIndicator in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

Help me create a progress indicator exactly like in the image of this link:
https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/1038/rF9o1y.png

this progress indicator is INDETERMINATE.

Comment: Asking how to create an entire new look for a control from scratch is too broad for Stack Overflow. There are books out there that cover creating custom controls. Try to implement this yourself first, then ask a question if you encounter a _specific_ problem. The basic idea would be to create a custom `Skin` and apply it to your `ProgressIndicator`. Your image looks like it could be two `Arc`s opposite each other. Or even just one `Arc` with a dashed stroke.

Comment: Ok i get your point. Thank you for giving me such an idea about dashed-stroke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution on my problem, thanks for the idea of @Slaw.

```
public class AnimatedNeonCircle extends Circle {

private     final       RotateTransition      transition;

public AnimatedNeonCircle (AnimatedNeonCircle.Animation a, double radius, double strokeWidth, Double... dashedArray) {
    this.transition = new RotateTransition (a.durationProperty ().get (), AnimatedNeonCircle.this);
    this.transition.setCycleCount (a.cycleCountProperty ().get ());
    this.transition.setAutoReverse (a.autoReverseProperty ().get ());
    this.transition.setByAngle (radius);

    super.setFill (Color.TRANSPARENT);
    super.setStroke (Color.CYAN);
    super.setStrokeWidth (strokeWidth);
    super.setEffect (new Glow (0.4));
    super.setRadius (radius);
    super.getStrokeDashArray ().setAll (dashedArray);
}

public void play () {
    transition.play ();
}

// =======================================================================

public static class Animation {

    private     final       SimpleObjectProperty <Duration>     duration        = new SimpleObjectProperty <> ();
    private     final       SimpleIntegerProperty               cycleCount      = new SimpleIntegerProperty ();
    private     final       SimpleBooleanProperty               autoReverse     = new SimpleBooleanProperty ();

    public Animation (Duration duration, int cycleCount, boolean autoReverse) {
        this.duration.set (duration);
        this.cycleCount.set (cycleCount);
        this.autoReverse.set (autoReverse);
    }

    public SimpleObjectProperty <Duration> durationProperty () { return duration; }
    public SimpleIntegerProperty cycleCountProperty () { return cycleCount; }
    public SimpleBooleanProperty autoReverseProperty () { return autoReverse; }

}
```